# Model to Controller back to Model? Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Codeigniter noob here.

I'm trying to display a user's profile when searched for but I need data from two separate tables. First I match the username to the userid, then I need to use that userid to access the profile information from a separate table. My view is able to display the userid with $query['userid'] but I am not sure how to pass this value back to the model?

Controller:

```
   public function get_profile()
{

     $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check|required');
      $username = $this->input->post('username');


     if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
     {
         $this->load->view('header_loggedin');
         $this->load->view('fail');
         $this->load->view('footer');
     }
     else
     {

         $data['query'] = $this->user_model->get_userid($username);
         $userid = $query['userid'];
         $data['row'] = $this->user_model->return_profile($userid);


         $this->load->view('header_loggedin');
        $this->load->view('user/user_profile', $data, $row);
        $this->load->view('footer');
     }
```

Model:

```
   function get_userid($username)
{
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('user');
  $this->db->where('username', $username);
  $query = $this->db->get();

  return $query->row_array();
 }

    public function return_profile($userid)
 {
   $data = array();
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('user_profile');
   $this->db->where('userid', $userid);
   $query = $this->db->get();

   return $query->row_array();

  }
```

View:

```
 <h3><?php echo $query['username'];?>- Public Profile</h3>

 <form id="profile" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="control-group">
 <i class="icon-user"></i>
 <b>Name:</b> <?php echo $row['name']; ?>   
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help. My error says that the $userid variable is not working in my controller. How can I pass that value back to a new model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks off:

```
$data['query'] = $this->user_model->get_userid($username);
$userid = $query['userid'];
$data['row'] = $this->user_model->return_profile($userid);
```

You may have meant to do something like this:

```
$user= $this->user_model->get_userid($username);
$data['row'] = $this->user_model->return_profile($user['userid']);
```

You are assigning `$data['query']` then trying to access a variable called `$query`. This wouldn't work. So you should fetch your user by id, then use that object to get your user profile.

EDIT

pass username to view:

```
$data['username'] = $username;
```

remember, `$data` array is being passed to the view in this line:

```
$this->load->view('user/user_profile', $data);
```

All keys of the `$data` array will be assigned as variables. So if you pass `$data['username']` it will be available as `$username` in the view.

Comment: Thanks Kai, this is working. I also need to pass the original username value to my view, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you! BTW if that fleeces website is actually yours I love it.

Comment: ha. yes it is. silly idea i built in a weekend. it makes money too. who would have known?